# Android USB to Serial Receive Error

Tags: java, android, multithreading, serial-port, usb

I'm currently working on writing an App on Android to interface with an Arduino Board. I am able to send serial data to my Arduino just fine, however my app crashes at start up the moment I begin trying to receive data.

I currently have it set so a text field takes data from a user, and sends to the Arduino, Arduino does a function.

For my receive, I am making a new thread at start up to constantly listen for data from the Arduino. whenever the code in this thread is executed, it crashes.

I am using this library as my basis: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Below is the all the code pertinent, omitted code for other functionality this app is providing, that are unrealted:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialDriver;


import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialProber;




     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener{

private EditText sendTextField;
    TextView uartRX;

 public Handler Handler; 


UsbManager manager;



/** Called to create application activity*/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    uartRX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rxUART);

    sendTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendTextField);






    Handler = new Handler() { 
        @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
        String text = (String)msg.obj; 
        uartRX.append(text); 




        } 
        };


        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run()
             {
                 Message msg = new Message(); 
                    msg.obj = "Start Serial Listen\n"; 
                    Handler.sendMessage(msg);
                 rxUART();
             }

            public void rxUART()
            {

                manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                UsbSerialDriver rxDriver = UsbSerialProber.acquire(manager);
                if (rxDriver != null) {
                      try {
                          rxDriver.open();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                int byteSize = 0;
                String data = "";
                while(true)
                {
                byte[] arr = null;
                try {
                    rxDriver.setBaudRate(115200);
                    rxDriver.read(arr, byteSize);
                    data = new String(arr);
                    Message msg = new Message(); 
                    msg.obj = data; 
                    Handler.sendMessage(msg);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }

    });
    t.start();

    }


public void sendUART(String data)
{
    manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    // Find the first available driver.
    UsbSerialDriver driver = UsbSerialProber.acquire(manager);
    if (driver != null) {
          try {
            driver.open();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
          try {
            driver.setBaudRate(115200);

            byte buffer[] = new byte[16];
            int numBytesRead = driver.read(buffer, 1000);
            Log.d(TAG, "Read " + numBytesRead + " bytes.");


            byte temp[] = data.getBytes();

            driver.write(temp, 16);

          } catch (IOException e) {
            // Deal with error.
          } finally {
            try {
                driver.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          } 
        }



}
   public void onClickSendBtn(View v)
    {
       String data = "";
       data = sendTextField.getText().toString();
       sendUART(data);
       sendTextField.setText(" ");
    } 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}







  }
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the app crashes on the code created in the thread?

Note: the code also crashes when not in a thread. Code was originally a function called by sendUART() to check for a response. no while(true) either.

Logcat:

```
   11-02 09:49:22.988: E/AndroidRuntime(22652): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-964
   11-02 09:49:22.988: E/AndroidRuntime(22652): java.lang.NullPointerException
   11-02 09:49:22.988: E/AndroidRuntime(22652):     at       com.example.sensortest.MainActivity$2.rxUART(MainActivity.java:143)
   11-02 09:49:22.988: E/AndroidRuntime(22652):     at com.example.sensortest.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:119)
   11-02 09:49:22.988: E/AndroidRuntime(22652):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The line numbers referenced are:

```
           Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run()
             {
                 Message msg = new Message(); 
                    msg.obj = "Start Serial Listen\n"; 
                    Handler.sendMessage(msg);
                 rxUART();
             }

            public void rxUART()
            {

                manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                UsbSerialDriver rxDriver = UsbSerialProber.acquire(manager);
                if (rxDriver != null) {
                      try {
                          rxDriver.open();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                int byteSize = 0;
                String data = "";
                while(true)
                {
                byte[] arr = null;
                try {
                    rxDriver.setBaudRate(115200);
                    rxDriver.read(arr, byteSize);
                    data = new String(arr);
                    Message msg = new Message(); 
                    msg.obj = data; 
                    Handler.sendMessage(msg);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }

    });
    t.start();
```

Comment: The output of `logcat` would be helpful.

Comment: @TurboJ I added the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't handle the case `rxDriver == null` in `rxUart()` correctly.

The `if()` statement skips the `open()` call only, but the `while()` loop gets executed with `rxDriver` being `NULL` resulting in NPE. You have the same problem in `sendUART(), btw.

Comment: thanks @TurboJ your advice, got me to try something else, and it worked. I'll update the code above.